# Return NULL for some values in multiple select SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website in PHP and have this piece of code:

```
INSERT INTO items (producttype, firstcode, secondcode, brand, retailer, firstsize, secondsize)
          SELECT ?, productcodes.id, productcodes.id, brands.id, retailers.id, sizes.id, sizes.id
          FROM productcodes, brands, retailers, sizes
          WHERE LOWER(productcodes.code)=LOWER(?)
          AND LOWER(productcodes.code)=LOWER(?)
          AND LOWER(brands.name)=LOWER(?)
          AND LOWER(retailers.name)=LOWER(?)
          AND LOWER(sizes.id)=LOWER(?)
          AND LOWER(sizes.id)=LOWER(?)
```

But when I have an input like this

```
INSERT INTO items (producttype, firstcode, secondcode, brand, retailer, firstsize, secondsize)
          SELECT 3, productcodes.id, productcodes.id, brands.id, retailers.id, sizes.id, sizes.id
          FROM productcodes, brands, retailers, sizes
          WHERE LOWER(productcodes.code)=LOWER(NULL)
          AND LOWER(productcodes.code)=LOWER(NULL)
          AND LOWER(brands.name)=LOWER('Canada')
          AND LOWER(retailers.name)=LOWER('WE')
          AND LOWER(sizes.id)=LOWER('XL')
          AND LOWER(sizes.id)=LOWER(NULL)
```

Even though most columns can be null (this is checked earlier on in the code. It returns null (empty) for all columns if only one is actually returning 0 rows.

Comment: `SELECT ?` fails because you cannot bind column names.

Comment: and the last two lines are contradictional. not both can be true. same with productcodes.code (if you have different values somewhen)

Comment: Sorry SELECT ? should be select 3 in the second piece of code, also thanks for the tip on the last 2 lines, I am inserting width and height here, but the values come from the same table, any tips on how to do that without contradiction?

Comment: @aynber you're partially correct. That `SELECT ?` cannot be used to specify a column name, but would be valid if he is using it for a `SELECT constant_value`.

Comment: `x = y1` and `x = y2` cannot both be true unless `y1=y2`; you most likely need to use OR for those fields.

Comment: Also, you can't really compare `column = NULL`. In databases, `NULL` usually means an unknown value (not empty). Anything compared to `NULL` returns `NULL` (a false value). Not even null itself is equal to null. Usually you have to query `column IS NULL` instead. `SELECT NULL=NULL` returns `NULL` where `SELECT NULL IS NULL` return 1 (true).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your great tips/suggestions/explanations.

I have managed to get my code working by using this query, it might be a huge hack or really heavy for the server, but for now it works. If anyone has any suggestions to improve on this code, please leave a message.

```
INSERT INTO items 
        (producttype, 
         firstcode, 
         secondcode, 
         brand, 
         retailer, 
         firstsize, 
         secondsize)
SELECT 3, 
   IFNULL((SELECT productcodes.id 
           FROM   productcodes 
           WHERE  LOWER(productcodes.code) = LOWER(NULL)), NULL), 
   IFNULL((SELECT productcodes.id 
           FROM   productcodes 
           WHERE  LOWER(productcodes.code) = LOWER(NULL)), NULL), 
   IFNULL((SELECT brands.id 
           FROM   brands 
           WHERE  LOWER(brands.name) = LOWER('Canada')), NULL), 
   IFNULL((SELECT retailers.id 
           FROM   retailers 
           WHERE  LOWER(retailers.name) = LOWER('WE')), NULL), 
   IFNULL((SELECT sizes.id 
           FROM   sizes 
           WHERE  LOWER(sizes.size) = LOWER('XL')), NULL), 
   IFNULL((SELECT sizes.id 
           FROM   sizes 
           WHERE  LOWER(sizes.size) = LOWER(NULL)), NULL)
```